# How to start xdg-open shortcut within conda environment (Using app installed with conda as xdg-open app)

Tags: xdg-open, conda, qgis

I installed QGIS using `conda`. If I start `qgis` from the terminal it works well as it has everything it needs to use in the PATH as defined by the conda `base` environment.

However I cannot pin that app to the dash, so I created an xdg-open shortcut:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/home/dzang/miniconda3/bin/qgis
Name=QGIS
Comment="QGIS 3.18"
Icon=/home/dzanaga/Pictures/Qgis-icon-3.0.png
```

When I use this Application shortcut, QGIS starts but then it doesn't work well since I guess it tries to use the system python/gdal. Basically some functionality is disabled and error messages pop up at the beginning.

So the question is, how to I configure the shortcut such that it starts QGIS as if it was started from within the `miniconda` `base` environment.
e.g. How do I have it running in a session where the PATH starts with `/home/dzang/miniconda3/bin:/home/dzang/miniconda3/condabin`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing:

```
Exec=env PATH=/home/dzang/miniconda3/bin /home/dzang/miniconda3/bin/qgis
```